# iOS - Core Bluetooth, detected service has no characteristics

Tags: ios, bluetooth, ios8

I have a problem with my bluetooth code that was working on iOS7 but is not on iOS8. My central code is detecting the service of the peripheral in the "peripheral didDiscoverServices" method. But it is not detecting any characteristics. For example in the code below when I print service.characteristics I get nil.

```
- (void) peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didDiscoverServices:(NSError *)error {

if (error) {
    NSLog(@"peripheral:didDiscoverServices: error = %@",error.debugDescription);
    return;
}

for (CBService *service in peripheral.services) {
    if ([service.UUID isEqual:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:kHotseatServiceUUID]]) {
        [peripheral discoverCharacteristics:nil forService:service];
        break;
    }
}}
```

I can confirm that that I am creating the service correctly for iOS8 (I hope). I only create and add the service to the peripheralManager once it has detected that bluetooth is powered on, see code below. Anyone have any ideas where I should look? Many thanks.

```
- (void) peripheralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBPeripheralManager *)peripheral {

if (peripheral.state != CBPeripheralManagerStatePoweredOn) return;

if (peripheral.state == CBPeripheralManagerStatePoweredOn) {
    [self buildTheHotseatService];  // this function is where I create & add the service, see below.
    [self.peripheralManager startAdvertising:@{ CBAdvertisementDataServiceUUIDsKey: @[[CBUUID UUIDWithString:kHotseatServiceUUID]] }];
}}

- (void) buildTheHotseatService {

// build the service
CBMutableService *hotseatService = [[CBMutableService alloc] initWithType:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:kHotseatServiceUUID] primary:YES];

// build the service characteristic
self.characteristicForStart = [[CBMutableCharacteristic alloc] initWithType:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:kHotseatCharacteristicUUIDForActivityStartDate] properties:CBCharacteristicPropertyRead value:[self.dataForCharacteristics objectForKey:kHotseatServiceCharacteristicKeyForActivityStart] permissions:CBAttributePermissionsReadable];
self.characteristicForTime = [[CBMutableCharacteristic alloc] initWithType:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:kHotseatCharacteristicUUIDForActivityTime] properties:CBCharacteristicPropertyRead value:[self.dataForCharacteristics objectForKey:kHotseatServiceCharacteristicKeyForActivityTime] permissions:CBAttributePermissionsReadable];
self.characteristicForDelay = [[CBMutableCharacteristic alloc] initWithType:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:kHotseatCharacteristicUUIDForActivityDelayTime] properties:CBCharacteristicPropertyRead value:[self.dataForCharacteristics objectForKey:kHotseatServiceCharacteristicKeyForActivityDelay] permissions:CBAttributePermissionsReadable];
self.characteristicForHaulProfileIdentifier = [[CBMutableCharacteristic alloc] initWithType:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:kHotseatCharacteristicUUIDForActivityHaulProfileIdentifier] properties:CBCharacteristicPropertyRead value:[self.dataForCharacteristics objectForKey:kHotseatServiceCharacteristicKeyForActivityHaulProfileIdentifier] permissions:CBAttributePermissionsReadable];
self.characteristicForType = [[CBMutableCharacteristic alloc] initWithType:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:kHotseatCharacteristicUUIDForActivityType] properties:CBCharacteristicPropertyRead value:[self.dataForCharacteristics objectForKey:kHotseatServiceCharacteristicKeyForActivityType] permissions:CBAttributePermissionsReadable];
self.characteristicForAuthenticationCode = [[CBMutableCharacteristic alloc] initWithType:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:kHotseatCharacteristicUUIDForActivityAuthenticationCode] properties:CBCharacteristicPropertyRead value:[self.dataForCharacteristics objectForKey:kHotseatServiceCharacteristicKeyForActivityAuthenticationCode] permissions:CBAttributePermissionsReadable];
self.characteristicForTruck = [[CBMutableCharacteristic alloc] initWithType:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:kHotseatCharacteristicUUIDForTruck] properties:CBCharacteristicPropertyRead value:[self.dataForCharacteristics objectForKey:kHotseatServiceCharacteristicKeyForTruckIdentifier] permissions:CBAttributePermissionsReadable];
self.characteristicForLoader = [[CBMutableCharacteristic alloc] initWithType:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:kHotseatCharacteristicUUIDForLoader] properties:CBCharacteristicPropertyRead value:[self.dataForCharacteristics objectForKey:kHotseatServiceCharacteristicKeyForLoaderIdentifier] permissions:CBAttributePermissionsReadable];
self.characteristicForInputReading = [[CBMutableCharacteristic alloc] initWithType:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:kHotseatCharacteristicUUIDForInputReading] properties:CBCharacteristicPropertyRead value:[self.dataForCharacteristics objectForKey:kHotseatServiceCharacteristicKeyForInputReading] permissions:CBAttributePermissionsReadable];
self.characteristicForInputType = [[CBMutableCharacteristic alloc] initWithType:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:kHotseatCharacteristicUUIDForInputType] properties:CBCharacteristicPropertyRead value:[self.dataForCharacteristics objectForKey:kHotseatServiceCharacteristicKeyForInputType] permissions:CBAttributePermissionsReadable];

self.characteristicForStartReading = [[CBMutableCharacteristic alloc] initWithType:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:kHotseatCharacteristicUUIDForStartReading] properties:CBCharacteristicPropertyRead value:[self.dataForCharacteristics objectForKey:kHotseatServiceCharacteristicKeyForStartReading] permissions:CBAttributePermissionsReadable];
self.characteristicForEndReading = [[CBMutableCharacteristic alloc] initWithType:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:kHotseatCharacteristicUUIDForEndReading] properties:CBCharacteristicPropertyRead value:[self.dataForCharacteristics objectForKey:kHotseatServiceCharacteristicKeyForEndReading] permissions:CBAttributePermissionsReadable];

// add the characteristic to the service
hotseatService.characteristics = @[self.characteristicForType, self.characteristicForTime, self.characteristicForStart, self.characteristicForHaulProfileIdentifier, self.characteristicForDelay, self.characteristicForAuthenticationCode, self.characteristicForTruck, self.characteristicForLoader, self.characteristicForInputType, self.characteristicForInputReading, self.characteristicForStartReading, self.characteristicForEndReading];

[self.peripheralManager addService:hotseatService];
```

}